# how to set multiple font colors in submit button

Tags: php, html, css

I'm stuck with designing my submit button.
I have a mysqli query which gives me x amount of records and I put some of the data onto a submit button in order to navigate to exactly that chosen data set on another page. So, what I have is a list with several buttons and whichever button I click I get the new page where these data are used for further queries etc.
It all works fine except I would like to change the color of one line on the button to focus attention but cannot work it out.

```
if ($This_Address == '') {
    $new_This_Address = "";     }
else {
    $new_This_Address = "&#13;&#10 this time: $This_Address";
}



       ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<form name="editTask" action="task_show_full.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="T_ID" value="<?php echo $T_ID; ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="Cust_ID" value="<?php echo $Cust_ID; ?>"/>
        <input type="submit" class="taskbutton" style="width:350px" name="showTask" 
        value="<?php echo "ID: ", $T_ID, ", ", "customer-ID: ", $Cust_ID, ", ", "User: ", $User; 
        ?>&#13;&#10 <?php echo $newFlat, $House, " ", $Street, ", ", $Town, ", ", $Postcode;
        echo $new_This_Address; 
        ?>&#13;&#10 <?php echo $Display_Task_Date, " ", $Task; ?>&#13;&#10 <?php
         echo $Price_Today, " ";
        ?>"/>
    </form>

<?php
```

The line in question is $new_This_Address. It should only show if there is something to show (which works so far) but it should also have a different color and so far I tried things like `<p>` or `<style color"blue">` but for some reason it is not willing to accept this as html but rather displays the commands as text.
What to do?

Comment: Look at your line starting `value="`. Everything following the quote (until the next quote) is read literally.  Just rearrange where your quotes are, and try again.

Comment: that is a NASTY abuse of the submit button. why can't you stuff all those values into SEPARATE hidden fields? they all submit with the form ANYWAYS, so why glue together a bunch of random/different data values, forcing to you go rip them apart at the server anyways?

Comment: @Marc B  well, I'm open for suggestions but if all the displayed data are hidden, which button will I choose (could be 100 or more of them) and which way to submit exactly these data would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<input type="submit">`, use a `<button>` instead.  You can put html directly inside of the button which will be evaluated (you can add colors & linebreaks).

```
<button>
  <?php echo "ID: ", $T_ID, ", ", "customer-ID: ", $Cust_ID, ", ", "User: ", $User; ?><br />
  <?php
    echo $newFlat, $House, " ", $Street, ", ", $Town, ", ", $Postcode;
    echo '<span style="color: red;">' . $new_This_Address . '</span>'; 
  ?><br />
  <?php echo $Display_Task_Date, " ", $Task; ?><br />
  <?php echo $Price_Today, " "; ?>
</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but changing to "button" doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it doesn't work.  I verified the code on my local server (it showed the variable $new_This_Address with red text inside the button because of the <span> I added).

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was simply changing `<input type="... ` to "button" and that didn't work. Now I used your code and added    <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script> to have the submit function covered and it works very well. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to format your text wherever you'd like. Using a span element is one option but there are many.

**INLINE**

```
$new_This_Address = "<span style='color: blue;'>This will be blue</span> and this is not";
```

**CSS Class**

```
.blue{
    color: blue;
}

$new_This_Address = "<span class='blue'>This will be blue</span> and this is not";
```

Comment: thanks, but this shows `<span... ` directly behind postcode